# Regex UserName for email should start or end with [a-zA-Z0-9] but may contain dash,underscore in between

Tags: c#, regex, string, match

There are many questions about email/username regex and I don't intend to add but I couldn't find exact answer. I am trying to match and replace email Id from a given string.

**Condition**:

1. Entire email id may contain (a-z,A-Z, 0-9,.,-,_)
2. user name or domain can be of 1 or more letters so `x@y.z` is a valid email.
3. user name and domain must start or end with [a-zA-z0-9]. i.e. shouldn't start or end with [ ._- ]

I am replacing them with a *** (3 asterisks) using following code.

```
string replacedtext = Regex.Replace("Emails: x@x.co.uk , -x@x.co.uk, x-@xx.co.uk , xx@xx-.com, xx@x.x.com-",  @"[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z-_]{2,6}", "***");
```

It works very well in most of the cases but fails in certain cases.

**Desired output**: `Emails: *** , -***, x-@xx.co.uk , xx@xx-.com, ***-`

**Current output**: `Emails: *** , ***, *** , ***, ***`

It replaces entire `-x@x.co.uk` where as it should only replace `x@x.co.uk` and ignore the hyphen.

Comment: Your third condition is unclear: "a-" is allowed according the first part of your sentence ("must start or end with [a-zA-z0-9]"), but not according the second part ("shouldn't start or end with [ \._- ]")

Comment: Also, I do not get the "xx@xx-.com" example. The domain "xx-.com" seems to fulfill all criteria, but you expect it to fai the match?

Comment: So the system will reject a person with their email (which works in the real world) because it fails **your** test? Seems like a foolish thing to validate emails as usernames in any system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+` by `[a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9\._-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?`.
In words: a (letter or digit), optionally followed by any number or (letter/digit/undescore/dash) + another (letter or digit)

```
Regex.Replace(
    "Emails: x@x.co.uk , -x@x.co.uk, x-@xx.co.uk , xx@xx-.com, xx@x.x.com-",
    @"[a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9._-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?@[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9._-]*?\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]*[a-zA-Z0-9]", 
    "***");
```

Also, note that the '.' needs to be esacped also within `[]`.